# Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined Error when using the project as NPM package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a npm components library where I am using vue `3.4.4` version and have created a custom directive.
The directive is created as in a `.tsx` file.

Stripped down version of code for the `.tsx` file.

```js
/** first get the component DOM built */
vueInstance = createApp({
  data() {
const obj = {} as WrapperVueData;
// eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
effectiveConfig.componentPropNames.forEach(name => ((obj as DirCompProps)[name] = options[name]));
obj.content = options.content;
// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
obj.isVisible__ = true;
return obj;
  },
  methods: {
onAfterLeave() {
},
onAfterEnter(el: HTMLElement) {
},
onEnterPopper() {
},
onLeavePopper() {
},
onResize() {

}
  },
  render(): VNode {/* eslint-disable-line */
const PopperComponent: any = effectiveConfig.component;/* eslint-disable-line */

const props: WrapperVueData = {} as WrapperVueData;
// eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
effectiveConfig.componentPropNames.forEach(name => (props[name] = this[name]));

let contentNode: any = null;
const self = this as WrapperVueInternalData;
if (typeof self.content === 'string') {
  contentNode = self.content;
} else if (typeof self.content === 'function') {
  contentNode = self.content();
}

const compNode = (
  <PopperComponent /////// Error is here.
    {...props }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    v-show={this.isVisible__}
    onRequestUpdate={this.onResize}
    onMouseenter={this.onEnterPopper}
    onMouseleave={this.onLeavePopper}
  >{contentNode}</PopperComponent>
);

const rootNode = options.doAnimation ? (
  <Transition
    name={effectiveConfig.visibleTransitionName}
    onAfterLeave={this.onAfterLeave}
    onAfterEnter={this.onAfterEnter}
    appear={true}
  >{ compNode }</Transition>
) : compNode;
return rootNode as VNode;
  },
  mounted() {
domService.resizeObserver.on(refEl, this.onResize);
domService.resizeObserver.on(this.$el.parentElement as HTMLElement, this.onResize);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
domService.resizeObserver.off(this.$el as HTMLElement, this.onResize);
domService.resizeObserver.off(refEl, this.onResize);
  },
  router: context ? context.router : undefined,
  parent: options.parentComponentInstance,
}) as PopperVueInstance;
```

**The above code works perfectly fine when I use it in the library.**

`vite.dev.config.js` looks like this.

```js
plugins: [
  vue(),
  checker({
    typescript: {
      root: './',
      tsconfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',
      buildMode: false,
    },
    eslint: {
      lintCommand: 'eslint "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}"',
    },
    vueTsc: true,
  }),
  vueJsx({
    babelPlugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    ],
  }),
  createHtmlPlugin({
    minify: true,
    entry: '/src/bootstrap.ts',
    template: 'index.html',
  }),
  basicSsl(),
],
```

Now this library is added as a package to other project with same vue version and same vite-dev.config.

When I use the directive there, I get the following error.

```bash
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Proxy.render (generate-directive.tsx:193:11)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:870:16)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5984:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:170:19)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6115:16)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6125:5)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5893:7)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5847:9)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5319:11)
    at render2 (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6635:7)
```

And the line `193:11` is the one from above tsx file where `/////// Error is here.` is written.

I already have vueJSX plugin in my vite config file.

In my `.tsconfig` I have these jsx specific configuration.

```json
"jsx": "preserve",
"skipLibCheck": true,
jsxImportSource": "vue"
```

**What configuration I am missing, because other vue based component from the library is working ?**

Comment: "Now this library is added as a package to other project" - in which way? Generally a library is built to spec-compliant JS before it's imported, so there would be no such problem with importing files that use JSX

Comment: Hey @EstusFlask library is used as npm package imported in other project and utilized.

Comment: Again, in which way? Do you bundle the library and import bundle file from lib's dist/, or import separate files from src/, or how is it done? It's unclear at which point uncompiled JSX appears. If you bundle it, check the bundle with your eyes for the appearance of `<PopperComponent`. It shouldn't exist there